# Recursion appears to duplicate some values randomly -- Advent of Code 2020 day 14 in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I’ve narrowed down the error (at least I think so) but still don’t know why it’s happening. For the dataset:

```
mask = 1XX010X01110X110100000X11101X10X0X11
mem[3513] = 1787222
mem[11652] = 13761
mem[25508] = 235920
mem[49386] = 7440645
mem[51287] = 197564380
mem[9697] = 1812
mem[62638] = 5207143
```

I get a sum that is off by the sum of values of the 4th memory entry (mem[49386] = 7440645) after the mask is applied. Applying the mask generates a correct value (I checked using successful algorithms posted by others). For some reason this address is being duplicated by my algorithm. I really suspect it is in this bit:

```
  def flip_bits(acc, []), do: acc

  def flip_bits(acc, [x | rest]) do
    acc
    |> Enum.flat_map(fn digits ->
      [List.update_at(digits, x, fn _ -> 1 end), List.update_at(digits, x, fn _ -> 0 end)]
    end)
    |> flip_bits(rest)
  end
```

The initial value for acc is a list containing the list of digits of the original address in binary after applying the one mask and padding to length 36. The argument [x | rest] is a list of indices in the mask at which an “X” was identified.

I cannot understand what is special about this one memory address that it gets duplicated. If I remove that one address I get the same answer as the successful algorithm. When I use the entire dataset my solution is off by more than just the value of this one entry, so it is clearly not JUST this value that is problematic. My hope is that someone can help me identify why this entry is problematic so that I can understand the flaw in my logic that generates what currently seems to me a random error.

Full code here:

```
defmodule Day14 do
  use Bitwise
  @moduledoc false

  @input File.read!("lib/input")

  def process(version \\ 1) do
    @input
    |> String.split("mask = ", trim: true)
    |> Enum.map(fn line -> process_line(line, version) end)
  end

  def process_line(line, version) do
    line
    |> String.split("\n", trim: true)
    |> Enum.with_index()
    |> Enum.reduce({[]}, fn {sub, ndx}, acc ->
      case ndx do
        0 ->
          sub
          |> process_mask(version)
          |> process_helper(0, acc)

        _ ->
          sub
          |> process_mem_assign(version)
          |> process_helper(acc)
      end
    end)
  end

  def process_mask(mask, 2) do
    one_mask = mask |> String.replace("X", "0")
    xs =
      mask
      |> String.codepoints()
      |> Enum.with_index()
      |> Enum.filter(&Kernel.==(elem(&1, 0), "X"))
      |> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 1))

    {one_mask, xs}

  end

  def process_mem_assign(sub, _version) do
    Regex.scan(~r/(?<=mem\[)\d+|(?<=]\s=\s)\d+/, sub)
    |> List.flatten()
    |> Enum.with_index()
    |> Enum.map(fn {match, _ndx} -> String.to_integer(match) end)
    |> List.to_tuple()
  end

  def process_helper(matches, 0, acc) do
    Tuple.insert_at(acc, 0, matches)
  end

  def process_helper(matches, {mask, assignments}) do
    {mask, [matches | assignments]}
  end

  def initialize(version \\ 1) do
    process(version)
    |> build_mem_map(version)
  end

  def build_mem_map(processed_lines, version \\ 1) do
    processed_lines
    |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {mask, assignments}, memory ->
      assign_memory(mask, assignments, memory, version)
    end)
  end

  def assign_memory(masks, assignments, memory, 2 = version) do
    assignments
    |> Enum.map(&apply_mask(&1, masks, version))
    |> Enum.reduce(memory, fn {addresses, val}, acc ->
      update_memory({addresses, val}, acc, version)
    end)
  end

  def apply_mask({address, value}, {one_mask, xs}, 2) do
    len = one_mask |> String.length()

    one_masked = (address ||| String.to_integer(one_mask, 2)) |> Integer.digits(2)

    {flip_bits(
       [
         1..(len - length(one_masked))
         |> Enum.reduce(one_masked, fn _, acc -> [0 | acc] end)
       ],
       xs
     ), value}

  end

  def flip_bits(acc, []) do
    acc
  end

  def flip_bits(acc, [x | rest]) do
    acc
    |> Enum.flat_map(fn digits ->
      [List.update_at(digits, x, fn _ -> 1 end), List.update_at(digits, x, fn _ -> 0 end)]
    end)
    |> flip_bits(rest)
  end

  def update_memory({addresses, val}, memory, 2) do
    addresses
    |> Enum.reduce(memory, fn address, acc ->
      Map.put(acc, Integer.undigits(address, 2), val)
    end)
  end

  def run2 do
    initialize(2)
    |> sum_memory()
    |> IO.puts()
  end

  def sum_memory(mem_map) do
    mem_map
    |> Map.values()
    |> Enum.sum()
  end
end

Day14.run2()
```

Comment: just a guess - when you split on `"\n"` are you sure all you input file's line-breaks don't have the odd carriage return character added?

Comment: The input file seems pretty clean, but even if not, an extra carriage return should yield an empty string that would be trimmed away.

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem I found is in this bit:

```elixir
[
  1..(len - length(one_masked))
  |> Enum.reduce(one_masked, fn _, acc -> [0 | acc] end)
]
```

You're trying to pad with 0s to `len`, but if `length(one_masked)` is equal to `len`, then you get `1..0`, which is equivalent to `[1, 0]`:

```elixir
iex(28)> 1..0 |> Enum.to_list
[1, 0]
```

You can just use `max` to cap this number from the bottom:

```elixir
1..max(1, len - length(one_masked))
```